# Beautiful Erlang Code

Tags: programming-languages, learning, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn more about Erlang than the toy projects I've been playing with. To this end, I'm reading through [Programming Erlang](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang) and some of the archives from [Armstrong on Software](http://armstrongonsoftware.blogspot.com/).

I would also like to read over some example (preferably production) code that showcases the sorts of things you can build with Erlang that would be disproportionately difficult in other languages. Aside from (I assume) [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/), are there any publicly available examples of beautiful Erlang code that I could read through to gain a better understanding of the language and/or see the idiomatic uses for various language constructs?

I'm specifically **not** looking for code that "gets the job done" but uses questionable practices, or examples along the lines of "here's how you write `factorial` in Erlang".

In the same vein, can anyone recommend any good literature for learning this language (other than the mentioned "Programming Erlang")? For preference, something you yourself used to learn it, but if there's some community standard books for it, throw those in too.

Comment: Erlang was created by Ericcson to design and build massively parallel switches for phone traffic. It was designed by Ericsson to support distributed, fault-tolerant, soft-real-time, non-stop applications. That is the problem domain in which it excels. For all other problem domains...Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another good reference is [Erlang and OTP in Action](http://www.manning.com/logan/).

About the code samples: it is kind of hard to find best practices for Erlang, but I would suggest you try these websites:

- [Trapexit](http://www.trapexit.org/)
- [Erlang Programming Language](http://www.erlang.org/)
- [Erlang Factory](http://www.erlang-factory.com/)
- [Planet Erlang](http://www.planeterlang.org/)
- [Erlang Solutions](http://www.erlang-solutions.com/)

Check the links from [this article](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/9/98014-erlang/fulltext) (open source software written in erlang) and you might find interesting code.

Answer (score -4):

Since you added the tag functional-programming, how about writing an Erlang compiler or interpreter in Haskell? Erlang is not quite state-of-the-art anymore, like at all.
I recommend to learn Erlang in one or two days, like some other languages (LISP, Prolog), and then to forget about them; they are just a step to unlearn imperative OOP-languages.

For smaller tasks than implementing a compiler, see [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

[EDIT]
To answer the comment:

From a technical view: Erlang was good in the old days, when there weren't multicore-processors. But now –given the existing compilers/interpreters I am arare of– it just does not scale anymore like it should. An interpreter written in Haskell would scale, compiled to Haskell would make it faster but would remove the on-the-fly code-replacing feature.

From the Programmers' view: Haskell is not for all applicable tasks the best choice, but atm, the probably more advanced languages are very experimental, and those not applicable tasks have usually sth to do with either embedded systems (like microcontrollers and GPUs) or numbercrunching, where C and Assembler are still the best choice.

What exactly is something that you could do with Erlang better than in other languages?

Comment: I didn't make a claim to be learning it because it was state-of-the-art; I just think it looks interesting, and there might be things you can build with it that you can't easily with other languages. If your answer is "Haskell is a better choice for all applicable tasks", how about telling me why specifically (instead of just asserting it vaguely), and answering the initial question for Haskell instead of Erlang?

Comment: I don't know that this answer is *that* bad, though it does skirt right around the original question. If you'd like to see some lovely Haskell in the sense that comanad is talking about, look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours Its a tutorial that teaches haskell, the parsec parsing library, and and scheme by writing a scheme parser. Parser combinators are, I feel, one of the more beautiful things to play with in functional languages. They're a bit practical too; once you know how to write parsers, you can design your own languages to solve specific problems.

Comment: As for Erland specifically, I'm sorry, but I have nothing to offer. I get the impression that it's in a state a lot like Smalltalk was/is: the system is proprietary, so actually getting an Erlang to use is hard, so there aren't many tutorials or examples written with it. The main strength of it is strong parallel programming in the FP style. If you just want to learn FP better, haskell is great, but F# may be better. F# lets you use the .NET runtime for all kinds of practical uses, and it has very good asynchronous code support.

Comment: "What exactly is something that you could do with Erlang better than in other languages?" I don't know; that's why I'm trying to learn it. My gut tells me that a language whose principal construct is the process (as opposed to the closure as in CL, the lambda as in Scheme or the dictionary as in python) would have something interesting to offer. Haskell is functional too, and it has similar pattern matching constructs, but there isn't a relentless focus on concurrency. In fact, the principal construct in Haskell seems to be the type, which makes me think they're very different animals.

Comment: @CodexArcanum - AFAIK, Erlang and OTP are available under a derivative of the Mozilla Public License, and it is free-as-in-beer from the Debian repos. What did you mean by "the system is proprietary"?

Comment: @comonad - What I meant by "Haskell is a better choice for all applicable tasks" was "For every task that I could complete acceptably with Erlang, Haskell can do it better". I didn't mean to imply that you could do all programming work with a single language, or that I was looking to use only one language for all my projects. You seemed to be asking "Why use Erlang when you can use Haskell?", which implies that you think Haskell is directly superior. I wanted you to clarify and perhaps support that claim.

Comment: @Inaimathi Hmm... According to wikipedia, Erlang was open-sourced in 1998. You'd think 12 years is plenty of time for folks to get on board, but Smalltalk had the same deal: never caught on when it was proprietary, and struggles as OSS. Erlang is also a programming system, a whole environment, not just a language, also like smalltalk, and like most LISPs. For some reason, it doesn't seem to me like language systems are as popular as compiled or interpreted stand-alone languages.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Well, yeah, I know that Haskell is my Blub(see http://paulgraham.com/avg.html) language. I know only of one feature, where Haskell is not superior to Erlang: you can exchange running code in Erlang. I can't think of anything else than that.

Comment: @Inaimathi: "language whose principal construct is the process" seems weird to me: Erlang has not many types, and so is not well-typed and has to be debugged often. ProcessIDs have their own types, that seems to be all to me. Well, it is easy to have better concurrency support in functional programs than in imperative, but I do compare functional languages. In Haskell, you have far more features for concurrency, like parallelizable arrays (an extension) and a great (small) library for concurrency. see Control.Concurrent in <http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/>

Comment: @comonad - That's why I downvoted you initially; the two languages seem to have little significant in common other than the pattern matching and functional paradigm. Erlang isn't strongly typed, and Haskell seems to have concurrency in the same way that Java has concurrency; as a library you can use. The reason I'm interested in Erlang is that it's built from the ground up with the assumption that your primary activity is going to be managing concurrent processes (possibly across multiple machines). Why did you recommend Haskell over it if you don't actually know much about Erlang?

Comment: @Inaimathi: I did learn Erlang once, maybe 7-10 years ago, but did never code much in it. That was before I learned Haskell. Actually, I compare Erlang's concurrency support to that of Java, while Haskell can do far more with concurrency than just realizing the Actor design pattern. This might be interesting: <http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html>

Comment: @Inaimathi: One example: Suppose, I already have an algorithm and want some parts of it parallelized to an unknown number of cpus. In that case, I just specify which chunks should be evaluated parallel (par) and which sequential (pseq). That is as easy as tagging on stackexchange.com, see <http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html#id691579>. The compiled program will have the number of OS-threads (=cpus) at the command line specified, on which it should run its internal lightweight haskell-level threads.

Comment: @comonad - That is interesting. I'll have to bookmark it to look over later; the parallel options are particularly arousing my curiosity. On reflection, we may be conflating parallelism and concurrency; initially I meant to refer specifically to concurrency in the sense of creating networks of inter-communicating nodes, not necessarily just multi-processing for performance. Sorry if I was unclear. (For the future, `<a>` tags don't work in comments, but if you paste the naked URL, it'll become a link like so: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html).

Comment: @Inaimathi: "networks of inter-communicating nodes", yeah, that might be very easy in Erlang, but I'm not that sure about reimplementing already existing protocols. In Haskell, I'd implement a library that wraps the TCP/Socket lib, and then use the Binary lib for serialization of Haskell values (which sounds of more than it is.). I did sth like that in my diploma thesis. It might look as easy as in Erlang, but I don't remember how Erlang comunicates over network. Dependant of the task, I would then prefer to design the flow with Arrows(fancy mathemagical stuff) instead of Actors(processes).

Comment: oh, i just found this click-through slide show:
http://www.slideshare.net/bos31337/the-other-side-of-functional-programming-haskell-for-erlang-people